# Another formula for the Schwinger term — problems with a calculation

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, quantum-field-theory, traces, clifford-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$I have a problem with understanding the proof of Proposition 6.8 in the book ,,Elements of Noncommutative Geometry''. One can find the formulation of this proposition [here](https://ibb.co/V2BHGkY) and the proof [here](https://ibb.co/dDhDHxS). The context is the following: $V$ is a *real* infinite dimensional vector space equipped with a *bilinear* form $g$: let us assume that the complex orthogonal structure $J$ is chosen, namely $J$ is an operator on $V$ such that $J^2=-I$ and $g(Jx,Jy)=g(x,y)$ for $x,y \in V$. This allows us to view $V$ as a *complex* vector space with the action $ix:=Jx$. Once $J$ is chosen, there is a scalar product $\langle x,y \rangle:=g(x,y)+ig(Jx,y)$. The space $V$ with this scalar product will be denoted by $V_J$. On the other hand, one can consider the complexification $V^{\mathbb{C}}$ of $V$ and equip it with the inner product $\langle \langle x,y \rangle \rangle:=2g^{\mathbb{C}}(\overline{x},y)$ where $g^{\mathbb{C}}$ is the extension of $g$ to the *bilinear* form on $V^{\mathbb{C}}$. One has then the projection $P_J:=\frac{1}{2}(I-iJ)$ in $V^{\mathbb{C}}$. If we put $W_J$ to be the range of this projection it turns out that viewing $P_J$ as an operator $V_J \to W_J$ yields a unitary $P_J$ (this is the reason to choose this constant $2$ in the definition of the inner product on $V^{\mathbb{C}}$). The Schiwger term is defined as $\alpha(A,B):=-\frac{1}{2} \Tr[A_-,B_-]$ where $A_-:=\frac{1}{2}(A+JAJ)$ is the *antilinear* part of $A$ (similarly for $B$) where $A$ is such that $[J,A]$ is Hilbert-Schimdt. Note that we are computing the trace of the commutator so the first impression is that it should be trivially zero-however our operators are antilinear-therefore it is nontrivial.

After explaining the general context let me explain where exactly my problems pop out: I don't see the last two equalities.

> The first one is as follows:
> $$\Tr(iP_J[A_-,B_-]P_J)+\Tr(-iP_{-J}[A_-,B_-]P_{-J})=2i\Tr(P_JA_-P_{-J}B_-P_J-P_JB_-P_{-J}A_-P_J)$$
> Here I don't see how the projection $P_{-J}$ appears in the middle of these two terms: $P_{-J}=I-P_J$ so one can have $P_J$ in the middle instead of $P_{-J}$ but still-there is no appearance of $P_J$ in the middle on the left hand side. I would like to see why this equality is valid

> For the second one, namely:
> $$2i\Tr(P_JA_-P_{-J}B_-P_J-P_JB_-P_{-J}A_-P_J)=-4i\alpha(A,B)$$
> authors claim that this follows since $P_J:V_J \to W_J$ is a unitary operator. As far as I understood-according to the formulation of the Proposition-$\alpha(A,B)$ is computed as a trace in $V^{\mathbb{C}}$ while the other trace probably takes place in $V_J$. But somehow these projections $P_J$ and $P_{-J}$ go the other way around so I'm confused what is really going on.

I will be very grateful for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combine the two questions in the OP in a single question: find a proof of proposition 6.8,
$$
\alpha(A,B)=\tfrac{1}{8}i\,{\rm Tr}\,J[J,A][J,B].\qquad\qquad(6.8)
$$

---

I note that the Schwinger term $\alpha(A,B)$ is defined as the trace of antilinear operators on a complex vector space, while the trace in (6.8) involves linear operators on a real vector space. The first step is then to rewrite the Schwinger term as a trace of linear operators on a real vector space,
\begin{equation}
\alpha(A,B)=\tfrac{1}{2}i\,{\rm Tr}\,J[A_-,B_-]=\tfrac{1}{8}i\,{\rm Tr}\,J[(A+JAJ),(B+JBJ)].\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
I have substituted the definitions
\begin{equation}
A_-=\tfrac{1}{2}(A+JAJ),\;\;B_-=\tfrac{1}{2}(B+JBJ),\qquad\qquad(2)
\end{equation}
where $J^2=-1$.

Since these are traces of linear operators, we can permute them cyclically, ${\rm Tr}\,XY={\rm Tr}\,YX$. I work out the trace in equation 1,
\begin{equation}
{\rm Tr}\,J[(A+JAJ),(B+JBJ)]=4\,{\rm Tr}\,J[A,B],\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}
and compare with
\begin{equation}
{\rm Tr}\,J[J,A][J,B]=2\,{\rm Tr}\,J[A,B].\qquad\qquad(4)
\end{equation}
I thus arrive at
\begin{equation}
\alpha(A,B)=\tfrac{1}{4}i\,{\rm Tr}\,J[J,A][J,B].\qquad\qquad(5)
\end{equation}
This is almost [proposition 6.8](https://ibb.co/V2BHGkY) from the book cited by the OP, except that there the coefficient is $1/8$ instead of $1/4$. I have searched for an [alternative source](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9402098) by the same authors, where the coefficient (on page 15) is given as $1/4$, like I found, so this is likely a typo in their book.

Comment: Thank you so much!